# "multiple defined symbols error" when using stdafx.h with own headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, header-files, precompiled-headers

I have some own made headers but whenever I use them with "stdafx.h", vs throw multiple defined symbols error for the function defined in the headers,

stdafx.h be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include "pUtils.h"
#include "pString.h"
#include "PodVector.h"
```

let's say I have a function defined in PodVector.h as
test_PodVector()

then i got error like:

> error LNK2005: "void
>   __cdecl test_PODVector(void)" (?test_PODVector@@YAXXZ) already defined in ar.obj 1>ar.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one
>   or more multiply defined symbols found

my main cpp file is like

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {    PodVector<int> vec;

    return 0; }
```

the errors go away if I make those functions static but why?

Comment: You are aware that `#include <stdafx.h>` always must be the 1st include statement?

Comment: yes it is in main cpp file

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] to get useful diagnosis of the problem here please.

Comment: Are you possibly having some non-`inline` functions in the headers?

Comment: yes they all are non-inline function

Comment: Then make them inline instead of static. :-) `static` creates *different* copies of the functions in each file, which is not good either.

Comment: Try adding #pragma once To your headers to prevent multiple definitions in your class declaration in the header file

Comment: #pragma once is in every header, but anyway I understood from the answers given in above already asked question